# Add request parameter to request

Tags: symfony

I need to put a flag in an `kernel.event_listener` at stage `kernel.controller` in order to do something in an `kernel.response`-listener.

I thought about adding a parameter to the `$request` object, however have not found any method or this:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

What is the best practice to pass some informatino from an `kernel.controller`-listener to an `kernel.response`-listener?

Use-case:

- We want to set a cookie based on a validation of a specific request attribute (must be in `kernel.controller`-stage, since based on the result of the validation, the view may behave different).
- The cookie can only be set in the `kernel.response`-listener, since it has the `Response`-instance.

Comment: Don't get your question. Why can't you just use a simple object that will store the cookies that you'll need to send before response is sent?

Comment: Thx, I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `$request->attributes` to pass around information. In your controller listener:

```php
$request->attributes->set('mykey', 'myvalue');
```

In your response listener:

```php
$myvalue = $request->attributes->get('mykey');
```