# How to set parameters to symfony2 request object

Tags: symfony, parameters, request

I am using symfony 2.3.2.

I have two fields "created" and "active" in my entity but i am not showing these fields to user interface ("new.html.twig").

In **createAction** method how can i assign values for these two fields in request object manually?

I tried using both ways

```
$request->attributes->set("active", "1");
$this->getRequest()->request->set('active', "1");
```

as suggested at [Add request parameter to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360651/add-request-parameter-to-request) and [Add Parameter to symfony2 Request deep array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214428/add-parameter-to-symfony2-request-deep-array) but it is not working and i am getting below error:-

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, email, password, active, created, modified) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["neeraj", "neeraj", "kumar", "neeraj.kumar@rsystems.com", "P@ssw0rd", null, null, null]:
```

Comment: These fields are static or generated?

Comment: These field are available in Database but i am not displaying them in user interface and want to pass values for those field manually from the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation i would use prePersist or preUpdate callbacks to set current date, look at [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: I want to assign current date time to field "created", so definitely i will have to pass this value to request object under createAction